# Get value in onclick based on row and column

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two div with id defined as time_slice and events respectively. 
time_slice parent id is block1 and block1 id position is absolute.
events parent id is block2 and block2 id position is relative.

I want someone click in events li tag in the same time time_slice li tag value get return. Here return only events li tag value.

When user clicks in the cell I want to retrieve the time value as well. Currently only the date is being populated.

But i don't want to change div to table structure.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#events li').on('click', function(event){
        $('#utest').html($(this).html());
        var eobj = new jQuery.Event("click");
        eobj.pageY = event.pageY;
        $(document).find('.timeline').trigger(eobj);    
   });
});

$('.timeline').on('click', function(){

});
```

[image]

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shivamanhar/ke6cmof2/)

Comment: *Sorry i can't explain more batter*?? Why?? Please explain more details with better explanation. :)

Comment: The html that you have created is not good. I would have created date as separate entity and each cell as independent entity. i.e. each cell should have been separate dom element. Anyway, I would recommend getting the click x and y and compare the y position with y position of each time to check which time lies in the same axis.

Answer (score 1):

this is it

```js
$("table td:not(:first-child)").on("click", function() {
  var time = $(this).parent().find("td:first-child").html(),
    date = $("table thead td").eq($(this).index()).html();
  $("table tfoot td").html(date + ' ' + time);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>2017-07-06</td>
      <td>2017-07-07</td>
      <td>2017-07-08</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>02:00</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02:30</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03:00</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03:30</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to make a scheduler calendar. like this https://alloyui.com/examples/scheduler. so events can't move and resize in table cell.

Comment: the example you provided is using a table. i didnt get the problem yet

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like a table, then you should use table instead of list.
Then get column and row indexes and then their values:

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
    //  Get row and column indexes
    var row_index = $(this).parent().index(),
        col_index = $(this).index();
    //  Get time and date values
    var time = $('tr:eq('+ row_index +') td:eq(0)').text(),
        date = $('tr:eq(0) td:eq('+ col_index +')').text();
    //  Just for a show
    alert(time + ' ' + date);
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/49cL65j1/37/

Comment: Sorry i don't want to table structure.

Comment: so what you need ? the picture says that